# Bash, grep lines from csv based on column 3, if length is 6 chars (numbers)

Tags: bash, csv, grep, width, line

**Question**

I need in bash, grep lines from `csv` based on `column 3` divided by `,`, only if it consists of solely *6 digits*.

**Example**

Input file.

```
,11,221951
,11,221952
,11,232928
,11,45
,11,4
,11,5
,11,6
,11,6
```

Output file (just lines based on 3th column, where are 6 chars).

```
,11,221951
,11,221952
,11,232928
```

**I tried**

```
cut -d, -f3 input_file.csv | grep -x '.\{6\}'
```

But it remove first two columns of course.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
awk -F',' '$3 ~ /^[0-9]{6}$/' file > newfile
```

Here,

- `-F','` sets the field separator to `,`
- `'$3 ~ /^[0-9]{6}$/'` keeps the lines where the third field value only consists of 6 digits.

See the  [online demo](https://ideone.com/o4aLCq):

```
s=",11,221951
,11,221952
,11,232928
,11,45
,11,4
,11,5
,11,6
,11,6"

awk -F',' '$3 ~ /^[0-9]{6}$/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
,11,221951
,11,221952
,11,232928
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what exactly I need, only numbers. Ravin, your solution is working too, but not for numbers only.

Comment: @genderbee, added 2nd solution too in my post now.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't understand? I accepted the solution immediately.

Comment: @genderbee Please consider accepting the answer to finalize the question.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} length($3)==6'  Input_file
```

In case you want to make sure all should be digits then try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} match($3,/^[0-9]{6}$/)'  Input_file
```

Comment: Small variation `awk -F, 'length($3)==6' file`

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) running

```
mlr --nidx --fs "," filter -S 'strlen($3)==6' input.csv
```

you will have

```
,11,221951
,11,221952
,11,232928
```